# TensorFlow: No allowing GPU memory growth option in contrib.learn. Estimator

Tags: memory, tensorflow, gpu, config

When creating estimator using contrib.learn, only GPU option that I can find is "gpu_memory_fraction" which can be found at "tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig"

```
classifier = learn.Estimator(
     model_fn=cnn_model_fn,
     config=learn.RunConfig(
           gpu_memory_fraction=0.9
           )
     )
```

Is there a way to allow GPU memory growth option when using contrib.learn ?

Answer (score 1):

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.9
run_config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig(session_config=config)
```

Pass above config to [Estimator's](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/RunConfig) session_config